# Probability of obtaining 2 hearts and 2 aces

Tags: combinations, playing-cards

I am really really struggling with this question and so far have not found an answer nor could figure it out correctly. I'll really appreciate if anybody can help answering the question with explanations. Thanks in advance!

You are to pick 4 cards randomly from a deck of cards that contains four suits and the following denominations: Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10.
There are no face-cards in this deck. "What is the probability of obtaining two Aces AND 2 hearts"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about basic probability math, not programming

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Sorry about that Sami. I am a new user, didn't really know where to post. But even if it's not programming related, it will be incredibly helpful if somebody can answer it. Thank you!